# Multiple locks - Behind the scene

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

```
class A {

Object lock1 = new Object();
Object lock2 = new Object();

List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

void insert1() {
    synchronized (lock1) {
        list1.add(5);
    }
}

void insert2() {
    synchronized (lock2) {
        list2.add(5);
    }
}

void firing() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        insert1();
        insert2();
    }
}
```

Above is an part of code, here thread t1 calls firing() and t2 calls firing().
I used lock1 and lock2 so that both thread will not wait to release the lock .
My question is what happens behind the scene ?

lock1 and lock2 object are members of class A.

Is there any relation between lock1 and lock2 with list1.add(5), list2.add(5), Are they also members of lock1 and lock2 Object ? or It is just used insted of this ?.

When used synchronized void insert1() and synchronized void insert2() or synchronized(this),  void insert1() and void insert2() are members of class A and lock of class A is acquired ,this happens behind the scenes but in above case two object are created just to acquire different lock.

What if I have many methods like void insert1() which are also needed to be synchronized than should I create that many locks = new Object(); ?

Comment: What is your intention? Now you're synchronizing access to methods of A instances

Comment: When used synchronized void insert1() and synchronized void insert2() or synchronized(this), I'm not synchronizing I'm just explaining what happens when you lock using A instances .

Comment: I need to know what happens behind when you use different lock instead for class lock itself

Comment: "*When used `synchronized void insert1()` or `synchronized(this)`, `void insert1()` and `void insert2()` are members of class A and lock of class A is acquired*"--no, they all acquire lock of **instance**, not class.

Comment: What if I have many methods like void insert1() which are also needed to be synchronized than should I create that many locks = new Object(); ?                      in this scenario creating too many locks  I don't think its good practice.

Comment: *"what happens behind when you use different lock"*--intrinsic lock of this particular object is acquired.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Yes they acquire lock of Class A instance.

Comment: *"many methods like void insert1() which are also needed to be synchronized"*-- you need to syncronize all methods between themselves or every method separately?

Comment: should look into a more thread safe list... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Comment: Think about idea to synchronize at lists themselves, like: `synchronized (list1) { list1.add(5); }`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Wow !, this can be done ?............I think it might

Comment: @JavedSolkar this is a common practice. Every object has intrinsic lock which can be used for synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`synchronized(lock1)` Does one thing, and *one thing only*:  It prevents other threads from synchronizing on the same object at the same time.  That's all.

Here's how and why you use it:

You have an object (e.g., `list1`) that has some kind of state, and you wish to update the object (i.e., change its state) by calling a method like `list1.add(...)`.  The problem that `synchronized` solves is, a method like `list1.add()` may have to put the object into a temporary, *invalid state* in order to effect the update.  You don't want any thread to be able to *look* at the state of list1 while some other thread is updating it.

So, you designate a lock object (e.g., `lock1` in your example).  And you make sure that *every block of code* in your program that either updates `list1` or even *looks at* `list1` does it inside a `synchronized(lock1){ ... }` block.

Since no two threads can synchronize on the same object at the same time, no two threads will be able to modify or use `list1` at the same time.

Comment: synchronized(lock1) Does one thing, and one thing only: It prevents other threads from synchronizing on the same object at the same time. That's it. End of story..................................Really straight forward : )

Comment: synchronized void insert1() and void insert2() {
    synchronized (lock2) {
        list2.add(5);
    }     }                                this should also work,  right ?

Comment: @JavedSolkar what do you mean, "work"?  What is the bad thing that you are trying to prevent from happening?  If you merely need to protect each list from internal corruption, then it will suffice to have one lock for each list.  If you need to protect some special relationship _between_ the two lists (e.g., both lists must always be the same length for some reason) then you would want to use a single lock for both lists.