# Multithreading on different objects' lock

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm a newbie in java programming and I know that Multithreading is not a trivial topic in Java, also I working as C developer for almost 3 years.

I've read this topic: "[Multiple locks - Behind the scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239770/multiple-locks-behind-the-scene)" and I understand it totally but I've one concern.

I update the code as follow:

```
package multithreading;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Worker {

    private List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    private void updateList1(int i) {
        synchronized (lock1) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Worker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            list1.add(1);
        }
    }

    private void updateList2(int i) {
        synchronized (lock2) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Worker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            list2.add(1);
        }
    }

    public void process(int ii) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            updateList1(ii);
            updateList2(ii);
        }
    }

    public void execute() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                process(1);
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                process(2);
            }
        });

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Worker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Time taken: " + (end - start));
        System.out.println("List1: " + list1.size() + "; list2: " + list2.size());
    }
}
```

And in the main class I created an object and called the execute method the output is:

`Time taken: 2186
List1: 2000; list2: 2000`

However if I made both functions (updateList1, updateList2) are `synchronized` and removed the synchronized block on `lock1` and `lock2`

the main will output:

`Time taken: 4342
List1: 2000; list2: 2000`

The concern is the code inside `execute()` calls `updateList1()` then `updateList2()` so it is a sequential calling for both methods, in the first code (using `synchronized` block) if one thread acquired the `lock1` and the other thread trying to call `updateList1()` it will be waiting for the `lock1` to be released by the other thread. So the time must be equivalent in both ways of implementation.

Please calrify the answer and sorry if I understand anything wrongly in Java because this scenario is what I know from my experience in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With synchronized methods only one of both methods can be executed at any given time. This leads to a sequential execution like the following (of course there a many other possibilities):

```
t1: updateList1             updateList2
t2:             updateList1             updateList2
```

Using synchronized statements on different lock objects instead, allows both methods to run simultaneously.

```
t1: updateList1 updateList2 updateList1 updateList2 
t2:             updateList1 updateList2 updateList1
```

After an initial step `updateList1` and `updateList2` can run in parallel. Since the methods require the same amount of time you also get an ideal speedup of 2 in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

The time is not the same, since in the case where you make `updateList1` and `updateList2` synchronized they use the `Worker` object as lock instance.

So in the second case, if one thread is running `updateList2`, the other thread cannot enter `updateList1`.

Answer (score 1):

- For your first case, there is no lock applied because locked objects
  are difference.
- For your second case, you remove the lock object,
  then, the lock object is now come to the instance of Test, which
  contains list1 and list2. In that case, when Test's synchronized are
  being accessed by Thread1, Thread2 need to wait and vicevesa.